# Searching for the source code of function `LinearNDInterpolator` in SciPy

Tags: python, github, scipy

I am trying to examine the function `LinearNDInterpolator` invoked in the following Python code

```
from scipy.interpolate.interpnd import LinearNDInterpolator
```

I came to the [SciPy GitHub branch scipy/scipy/interpolate](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/interpolate) but can not find 'interpnd' much less `LinearNDInterpolator`. The function [scipy/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py) uses the function `LinearNDInterpolator`. I suspect this is because `interpnd` is not a Python script but something like C++ or even Fortran that Python is wrapping around. Is this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's written in [Cython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython).
[Source code link](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/193f160feeeb6256d26ba7d42c627910bc78d4a5/scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx#L205)

Comment: Thank you. How do you find it?

Comment: The file is in the [Git folder](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/interpolate) you linked. You probably looked over it since it has the `pyx` Cython extension.

Comment: That is it! Thank you, Laurens.

Comment: Care to take a look at  my closely related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54014959/2227222?