# In PyCharm, how to break at a line in an imported Cython extension code

Tags: python, pycharm, cython

I am trying to examine the function `LinearNDInterpolator` invoked in the following Python code

```
from scipy.interpolate.interpnd import LinearNDInterpolator
```

I would like to run a Python script invoking function `LinearNDInterpolator` and set a breakpoint at, say, [line 304 of function `LinearNDInterpolator`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/193f160feeeb6256d26ba7d42c627910bc78d4a5/scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx#L304). How can I do this?

I am using PyCharm. I am not able to "step into" the code of `LinearNDInterpolator`. The following is an example script I am running.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate.interpnd import LinearNDInterpolator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y =  np.linspace(-1,1,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

def f(x, y):
    s = np.hypot(x, y)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    tau = s + s*(1-s)/5 * np.sin(6*phi) 
    return 5*(1-tau) + tau

T = f(X, Y)
# Choose npts random point from the discrete domain of our model function
npts = 400
px, py = np.random.choice(x, npts), np.random.choice(y, npts)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
# Plot the model function and the randomly selected sample points
ax[0,0].contourf(X, Y, T)
ax[0,0].scatter(px, py, c='k', alpha=0.2, marker='.')
ax[0,0].set_title('Sample points on f(X,Y)')

# Interpolate using three different methods and plot
i = 0
method = 'linear'
#for i, method in enumerate(('nearest', 'linear', 'cubic')):
ip = LinearNDInterpolator((px, py), f(px,py))
Ti = ip((X, Y))
r, c = (i+1) // 2, (i+1) % 2
ax[r,c].contourf(X, Y, Ti)
ax[r,c].set_title('method = {}'.format(method))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does putting `breakpoint()` work? It's only for Python 3.7+ though.

Comment: @GeeTransit: Where do I put `breakpoint()`?

Comment: Can you access the code of `LinearNDInterpolator`? You can make a copy of that and import it as a python file, though that may break the package. Maybe [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) will help.

Comment: @GeeTransit: I tried copying the Cython file into my local directory in PyCharm with the file name 'interpnd.pyx', importing the function with command `from interpnd import LinearNDInterpolator`. I encountered the error "ImportError: No module named interpnd". Does PyCharm allow adding a Cython file with the `.pyx` extension to the local directory?

Comment: Check out the [debugging section](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/debugging.html) of the Cython docs.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - Sample code works for me minus commented out line that was in error

[image]

So I tested this myself.

Find the site-packages folder to find the scipy source files

In powershell

```
python -m site
```

For me this folder was
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy

open the **init**.py file in pycharm and set your break point on the first line of code

```
__all__ = ['test'] <- breakpoint there
```

Run > Debug > Step Into My Code

[image]

Comment: Is your `__init__.py` part of scipy? In any case, could you please try my import script and set the breakpoint at the line I specified in my question?

Comment: What is the first line of code where you use LinearNDInterpolator?

Comment: I added an example Python script invoking the Cython function. See if you can run it.

Comment: Says "NameError: name 'xi' is not defined"

Comment: Now Says "NameError: name 'method' is not defined"

Comment: I commented out the code that was erroring and I got a plot. See edit update in my answer with screenshot.

Comment: So, are you able to answer my question?

Comment: Sorry. I misread your question the first time which lead to my answer. Doesn't look like you can debug cython exts in pycharm or even with python debugger. Need to use the cython debugger. I will look into this tomorrow. Need to sleep now.

Comment: This is the best info I got so far - https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/DebuggingTechniques - Seems like if you could setup your environment to build scipy/interpnd then you would be able to debug the extension code. I reached as far as it telling me I needed lapack / fortran.

Comment: OK, thanks. This echoes what @LaurensDeprost said in the top comment section.

Comment: Following up to see if you got anywhere with this?

Comment: Not yet. I am trying to get PyCharm to recognize .pyx Cython files. Apparently, only the paid Professional version does.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? At one point I was thinking about loading Linux in a VM and seeing if that would make build scipy.

Comment: I will try. I was able to follow the hello world example from Cython docs. Then moved on to trying interpnd.pyx but at the top of that file says, "Note: this file should be run through the Mako template engine before feeding it to Cython" but I am not seeing a template file in the source directory.